# Silencing cherrypy access log for a particular method/api/url

Tags: python, cherrypy

The problem is simple, we would like CherryPy to not log access log for a particular exposed method/API that gets called.

Basically when this API gets called, there are some parameters in the query string of the URL which are very sensitive and if leaked, would expose potential security. Naturally this is a /GET request and unfortunately it is the only way the parameters could be passed, since its a redirect(302) from an external service to this web server.

If it would not log the URL, that would serve the purpose as well.

So, is there a way that we can filter logging messages in access log by API's, URL's etc?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

cherrypy uses Python's standard `logging` module by default, so you can just add a custom filter. This example will ignore any GET request with `/foo` as the path prefix:

```
import logging

class IgnoreURLFilter(logging.Filter):
    # simple example of log message filtering

    def __init__(self, ignore):
        self.ignore = 'GET /' + ignore

    def filter(self, record):
        return self.ignore not in record.getMessage()

app = cherrypy.tree.mount( YourApplication() )
app.log.access_log.addFilter( IgnoreURLFilter('foo') )
cherrypy.engine.start()
```

Comment: can use in conjunction with https://pypi.org/project/apachelogs